# Debugging Dalvik VM

Tags: android, debugging, compilation, dalvik

I am tweaking and compiling the source code of Android 2.1.

I wish to debug changes I have made to the Dalvik VM, specifically to the file
dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.c.

What do I need to do to enable debugging? And once it is enabled, how do I do it?

In fact, just enabling the dalvik system logs would suffice for my needs. Throughout the (native) code of the virtual machine there is use of the macros LOGE, LOGD, etc... But when I use it them it causes a segmentation fault. When used in the code (not by me), it is only used if NDEBUG is defined (#ifdef), so I assume the problem is again that debugging is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging the dalvik vm is no different than any sort of native debugging on Android. You use gdbserver on the device to attach to the process you want to debug, forward the port from the device to your local machine with adb forward, and then use gdb on your local machine to connect to the forwarded port.

For more information, see development/docs/porting/debugging_native.jd in AOSP. Note however, that some of the information there might be out of date.